# unordered_map error in GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

When was the `unordered_map` concept built into g++?

Because the following code throws an error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

std::unordered_map<std::int,int> mirror;

mirror['A'] = 'A';
mirror['B'] = '#';
mirror['E'] = 3;

int main(void)
{
    std::cout<<mirror['A'];
    std::cout<<mirror['B'];
    std::cout<<mirror['C'];
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling the code as follows:

```
g++ -c hashexample.cpp
g++ -o result hashExample.o
./result
```

The error I got is this:

> inavalid types int[char[ for aaray subscript

What is the fix for this?

Comment: Apart from the solutions offered below you can consider changing your template from <int,int> to <char, int> as you are using only chars for providing the key. Just an observation/suggestion!

Comment: that should not even compile because of the `std::int`, which is not valid C++.

Comment: `stdio.h` has been deprecated in C++ since at least 13 years ago, and why are you not indenting your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your assignment. You cannot assign values to your map in this place. C++ is not a script language.
This program works fine on my machine with gcc4.6:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<int,int> mirror;

int main() {
    mirror['A'] = 'A';
    mirror['B'] = '#';
    mirror['E'] = 3;

    std::cout<<mirror['A'];
    std::cout<<mirror['B'];
    std::cout<<mirror['C'];
}
```

Comment: You can do it "in this way", just not "in this place"!

Comment: yeah, I saw that too. however I cannot put it in main.

Answer (score 5):

First, as mkaes points out, you cannot put assignments outside functions, so you have to put it in any, for example `main`.

As for `unordered_map`, for recent versions of gcc, if you don't want to go into C++11, you can use the TR1 version of `unordered_map`:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
```

and the type `std::tr1::unordered_map`. You know, C++11 supersedes all this, but you will (at least in GCC) get this working.